# Automatically shift down or insert cells so don't get "Array not expanded, would overwite data" error

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, split, insert, overwrite

I'm making a Google Sheet for the roleplaying game Pathfinder in which I want to be able to copy and paste different monster stat blocks from another site to column A and have each section put into individual cells in column B and other columns using SPLIT, etc. Then eventually I want to be able to add different templates onto that, such as the skeleton template, which automatically alter some of the stats.

But I'm having trouble in that because the stat blocks can vary a lot between monsters Spell-like Abilities (SLA's) can be blank for some monsters and have very many for others. I have an array formula to get all the data between "Spell-Like Abilities" and the next section down, "Statistics," and SPLIT each SLA out in column B. But if there are too many SLA's it gets the overwrite error because the result would go over the sections/formulas below that in column B.

I could just move those lower column B sections down to have enough room but because I don't know how many SLA's any monster might have I don't know how many cells of space I would need to leave open. I could leave as many as say 25 but what if a monster I don't know has 26? Plus I don't want to leave a lot of blank space in column B like that as it would make it harder to read or deal with and would be blank most of the time and useless.

So I have been trying to find a way that the right amount of blank cells would be added in automatically for the SLA part in column B for every monster I paste in column A, shifting the cells below it down accordingly. However, I have not been able to find a formula or script that can do this. I could add a part to the formula to count how many cells are between "Spell-Like Abilities" and "Statistics" and use that to know how much space I need but I can't find a formula that adds cells or shifts down cells.

Edit:Edit: The cell is B21. Right now I have a lot of blank cells below that with STATISTICS in cell B41 and other cells with formulas below that. If I move "STATISTICS" up too high I get the error depending on how many SLA's or spells the monster has. Ideally I want B21 to have no blank cells below it by default so I can have STATISTICS in cell B22 or B23. And then whatever stat block I post in column A I want to push STATISTICS and all cells below it down the necessary amount of cells so that the overwrite error doesn't happen. If the monster has no SLA's it won't move. If it has 15 rows of SLA's then STATISTICS and all cells below it will move down 14 so there are 15 cells (counting B21 itself) to display those SLA's in column B.

Here is my formula in that cell. Edit: updated:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(JOIN("@", (REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE((INDIRECT("A"&(ARRAYFORMULA(MIN(IF(REGEXMATCH(A1:A40, "Spell-Like|Spells Known"), ROW(A1:A40), )))+2))):(INDIRECT("A"&(ARRAYFORMULA(MIN(IF(REGEXMATCH(A:A, "TACTICS|STATISTICS"), ROW(A:A), )))-2))),"Known","Known:;"),"Prepared","Prepared:;"))), "@")), ",""—"";"))
```

There is + and - 2 because the actual SLA's have a blank space above and below them in the section.

Here is an example of what it comes out to with Statistics below.

|    Constant    |    protection from good  |

|    3/day    |    detect thoughts (DC 13)    |    dream (DC 16)    |    nightmare (DC 16)    |     suggestion (DC 14)    |

|    1/day    |    shadow walk    |

STATISTICS

Here is the sheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1R8LYW2HGhpM3TS9m4ZBaNstwzNtsyll9fZnQ8WaA3Nc/edit#gid=0

Comment: What do you mean by 'right amount of blank cells'? The values are split into Columns C and onwards and columns are inserted automatically. I cannot get your problem and goal. Also, please specify the cell.

Comment: @idfurw okay I added an Edit explaining the specifics more.

Comment: Actually not only STATISTIC but all the cells (rows) after it are affected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]
[image]

The original formulas are complicated so I just answer with a simple example.
Please modify it yourself.

`=ArrayFormula(SPLIT({ INDIRECT("A"&MATCH("Section A",A:A,0)&":A"&MATCH("Section B",A:A,0)-2); "(blank)"; INDIRECT("A"&MATCH("Section B",A:A,0)&":A"&MATCH("Section C",A:A,0)-2); "(blank)"; INDIRECT("A"&MATCH("Section C",A:A,0)&":A"&MATCH("Section C",A:A,0)+2) },","))`

---

Perform different split on each array

`=ARRAYFORMULA(SPLIT({A76;A77},IF(REGEXMATCH({A76;A77},";"),";",",")))`

Comment: Okay I tried out your example and that works, I'll have to try to incorporate it into my sheet fully later tonight. I may have to rewrite my whole thing and put it in once cell like that.

Comment: I was trying to use your formula but I've run into an issue. Some sections I had split by comma and semicolon, some only by semicolon because splitting the comma would screw up sentences. I set it so the overall split was semicolon then was trying to put splits for each section for comma if it needed it. However it got an error "In ARRAY_LITERAL, an Array Literal was missing values for one or more rows." Which I found out meant there were different numbers of columns in different rows and the array can't work with that. The different number of columns is caused by the other splits.

Comment: I have a sample of it in B65 with error.

'=ArrayFormula(SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE
({SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(INDIRECT("A1"&":A"&MATCH("Init"&"*",A:A,0)-1),"\(",",("),",");
(SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(INDIRECT("A"&MATCH("Init"&"*",A:A,0)&":A"&MATCH("DEFENSE",A:A,0)-1),"\(",",("),","))
},", DC"," DC"),";"))'

Comment: Yes, the each array in the same group (surrounded by the same `{}`) should have the same number of column, meaning that you cannot split each of them separately. But with an `IF` as shown the added example, you can do so.

Comment: Okay I have it working. I couldn't use the IF way because some used both semicolon and comma, some only comma, some only semicolon, some neither. I had to use your first formula and broke it into 5 sections based on there differences and had the whole range SPLIT by semicolon. I replaced commas with semicolons using REGEXREPLACE in certain sections.